# Which timezone to setup in server: Etc/UTC or Etc/Universal?

Tags: linux, time, timezone, administration

Both timezones (Etc/UTC & Etc/Universal) available on ubuntu 10.04. Can;t figure out which one to choose for the web server.

My theory that Etc/UTC points to the particular time zone rather then Etc/Universal is semantically points to the current "base" time. So Universal is the option of choice.

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to Server Fault?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etc/Universal is simply an older naming standard for Etc/UTC. The same goes for Etc/Zulo. It works, it is in every practical aspect the same, but if you want to be really correct; Etc/UTC is the one to pick.

From the tz database etcetera file:

```
# The following link uses older naming conventions,
# but it belongs here, not in the file `backward',
# as functions like gmtime load the "GMT" file to handle leap seconds properly.
# We want this to work even on installations that omit the other older names.

Link    Etc/UTC             Etc/Universal
Link    Etc/UTC             Etc/Zulu
```